# Reshape a numpy array of ndim2 to ndim3 to be usable by GRU layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I built a model that is running on 2D midi arrays, and research on different Keras layers lead to me attempting to use GRU/LSTM layering to improve my model rather than simply dense layers.
Here is my model below:

```
model = keras.Sequential(
  [
    #layers.Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=2),
    #model.add(keras.Input(shape=(100, , )))
    #model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
    layers.GRU(100, return_state=True, return_sequences=True),
    layers.GRU(85, return_state=True, return_sequences=True,),
    layers.GRU(75, return_state=True, return_sequences=True),
    layers.GRU(65, return_state=True, return_sequences=True),
    layers.GRU(35, return_state=True, return_sequences=True),
    layers.GRU(25, return_state=True, return_sequences=False),
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(units =100, activation='relu')),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='relu')
  
  ]
)
model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

Have attempted to call reshape during the model.fit to ensure it can be passed through, but it failed.

Here is where I call model.fit and receive the "Input 0 of layer "gru" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100)" error:

```
for i in range(20):
      x = None
      y = None
      gc.collect()
      for j in range(10):
          print(10* i + j)
          new_x = np.load("Location of x training data" + str(10* i + j) + ".npy")
          new_y = np.load("Location of y training data" + str(10* i + j) + ".npy")
          if x is None and y is None:
              x = new_x
              y = new_y
          else:
              x = np.concatenate((x, new_x))
              y = np.concatenate((y, new_y))
      print(x.shape)
      print(y.shape)
      
      model.fit(x, y, validation_data = (new_x, new_y), epochs = 1) #Error
      model.summary()
```

How can I get this to work?

Attempted to use embedding layer and reshape the x and y within the model fit statement

Comment: expected input dimension is `[batch, timesteps, feature]` but you are feeding only 2dim.

Comment: Is there e any work around for that? My input data is only 2D so mainly looking for the proper way to create an embedding or to call reshape on my x and y so it can work. if its impossible w/o adjusting my input array then i'll accept that as a solution

Comment: GRUs are for sequence/time series data, if you do not have that kind of data, you cannot use them with that kind of model, there is no workaround. Is your data sequence or time series?

Comment: The files being passed in are MIDI, so time series